# Let R be a ring with unity and S be the set of all units in R

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I need to prove two things

(a) prove or disprove that $S$ is a subring of $R$

(b) prove or disprove that $S$ is a group with respect to multiplication in $R$

For (a) (1) it is clearly that $S$ is non empty since it contains the identity (The unity)

(2) let $a,b \cap S$ then $ab \in S$ because for $a$ we know there is an element $x$ such that $ax = e$ and for $b$ we know what there exists an element $y$ such that $by = e$ and so $ab(yx) = a(by)x = aex = ax = e$ and so $ab \in S$

$a - b \in S$ i am stuck here ! any suggestions

for (b) i think we already proved that it is closed under multiplication and have the identity and it is trivial to prove that all elements have inverses and are also associative , so yes it is a group under multiplication

Comment: sum of two units is not necessarily a unit

Comment: so you mean i can find a counter example ?

Comment: Yes take the ring of real numbers. $1$ is a unit, $1+1=2$ is not a unit

Comment: that makes perfect sense , thanks a lot . But it is a group like i said right ?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly correct.

Comment: is there another example of a ring with more than two units that add up to an element which is not a unit ?

Comment: In ring of complex numbers, units are $1,-1,i,-i$. You can clearly see any two units does not add up to a unit.

Comment: hey you meant to say that Ring of unity with respect to Integers not reals right ?

Comment: Yes, in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @Sayan What is your definition of a "unit"?  I thought a unit was an element with a multiplicative inverse.  $1 + 1 = 2$ *is* a unit in the ring $\mathbb{R}$... $\frac{1}{2}$ is its multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was referring to the rings of integers in that example.

Comment: if I remember correctly, when $S$ is an ideal of $R$, we call such rings _local rings_.

Answer (score 4):

For the case (a), you already mentioned that $S$ is non-empty as $1 \in S$. But $1 - 1 = 0$ does not belong to $S$, unless $1 = 0,$ i.e. unless $R$ is the trivial ring. So if $R$ is non-trivial then $S$ can not be a subring.

Answer (score -1):

Since in any ring, the additive identity is not a unit, it can not belong to the set of units, which can therefore never be a subring.